# Cambiar el valor de un textarea desde botones en CKEDITOR - Laravel

Tags: php, javascript, html, laravel, ckeditor

Bien, el tema es el siguiente, implementé CKEDITOR en mi proyecto de Laravel para poder usar imágenes y formato de texto dentro de algunos textarea. El asunto es que antes de implementarlo tenía un pequeño script que cambiaba el valor del textarea añadiendo texto predefinido que tenía en unos botones.

Luego de implementar CKEDITOR, este script no funciona correctamente, resulta que cambia el valor del textarea pero no lo muestra en el editor de CKEDITOR. ¿cómo se que cambia el valor? porque cuando recargo la página del formulario, luego del refresh aparece mágicamente todos los valores que fui añadiendo con los botones.

Les dejo el HTML donde se encuentra el textarea:

```
<div class="form-group">
                          <label>Seleccione los elementos que desee añadir:</label><br>

                          {{-- HOMBRO --}}
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
                          onclick="addEFSElement('Usted seleccionó hombro.')">
                          Hombro
                          </button>

                          {{-- PIERNA --}}
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
                          onclick="addEFSElement('Usted seleccionó pierna.')">
                          Pierna
                          </button>

                          <textarea name="lmr_examenfs" id="lmr_examenfs" rows="8" cols="80" class="ckeditor">

                          </textarea>
                        </div>
```

Código JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                function addEFSElement(text){
                var actualText = $("#lmr_examenfs").val();
                var newText =  actualText +" "+ text;
                $("#lmr_examenfs").val(newText);                    
                }

                CKEDITOR.replace( 'lmr_encabezado' );
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'lmr_antecedentes' );
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'lmr_examenfs' );


                </script>
```

Debo decir que intenté utilizar lo siguiente:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646948/how-to-make-ckeditor-update-the-text-content-without-using-jquery

Pero no me ha resultado, también probe distintas soluciones que encontré en StackOverflow y todas siguen sin funcionar, no updatean en tiempo real el textarea como lo hacía antes de instalar CKEDITOR.

Desde ya agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Lo he solucionado por mi cuenta. Les dejo como lo hice:

Modifiqué el script que se ejecuta al presionar el botón de la siguiente manera:

```
function addEFSPierna()
                {
                  var text = CKEDITOR.instances["lmr_examenfs"].getData();
                  var newText = "<p>Prueba</p>";
                  CKEDITOR.instances["lmr_examenfs"].setData(text + newText);
                }
```

Comment: buenas dias, por lo que estuve viendo en tu pregunta estas añadiendo un texto que ya tiene elaborado con anerioridad y quisiera consultarte algo. Yo estoy intentando crear en CKEDITOR un boton que me permita poner una etiqueta dentro de mi CKEDITOR y que cuando salve el contenido para mi base de datos me guarde solo el contenido que esta dentro de la etiqueta que le incorpore. comprendes lo que intento explicar. gracias